# Framework7 pass object as params between pages

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

How can I send an array object between pages in Framework7? I can send variable values but cannot understand how to send objects?

I have an array object like this

```
    "phoneNumbers": [{
        "number": "(555) 564-8583",
        "normalizedNumber": "(555) 564-8583",
        "type": "MOBILE"
    }, {
        "number": "(415) 555-3695",
        "normalizedNumber": "(415) 555-3695",
        "type": "OTHER"
    }]
```

In route.js

```
  {
    path: '/contact/:id/:phoneNumbers/',
    componentUrl: './pages/contact.html',
  },
```

index.html

```
<a href="/contact/{{this.id}}/{{this.phoneNumbers}}/"></a>
```

contact.html

```
  <p>{{this.$route.params.id}}</p>
  <p>{{js 'return JSON.stringify(this.$route.params.phoneNumbers)'}}</p>
```

In `contact.html` it doesnt show the array object, instead it returns this

```
"1"
"[object Object],[object Object]"
```

I want to know if it is possible to send objects using Framework7's router?

Alternate approach I took was using `localStorage`, but is there a way in Framework7 to send objects between pages and not only variables?

Comment: Interested too,  I got like this case and I resolve it by context, dependence of params I create context thats pass to page. also a local-storage its one of our solution

Comment: one of solution is send object as string in param, and parse It in target page. (by using custom helper, or init process ...

Comment: By `resolve it by context` you mean you abstract the keys in the object and send its value? That is possible but some object can be too big.

Comment: I mean F7 context, every page has an data context can be pass to page...so that I set trigger js and navigate with context option...https://framework7.io/docs/routes.html (context) also this https://framework7.io/docs/view.html#router-api-methods-properties `(router.navigate(url, options))` - router,navigate resolve your issue sure...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specifics of your use case but usually I make the data I want to pass global to the app by placing it in the javascript `window` object. It will be available to your code on the subsequent page(s) the user enters. It's more efficient than using localstorage.

```
window.phoneNumbers = [{
        "number": "(555) 564-8583",
        "normalizedNumber": "(555) 564-8583",
        "type": "MOBILE"
    }, {
        "number": "(415) 555-3695",
        "normalizedNumber": "(415) 555-3695",
        "type": "OTHER"
    }]
```